# manage field in create content is not appearing drupal 6

Tags: drupal-6

I created a new content type called "test" in drupal 6.under the "test" i add a new field "home" in manage display and save configuration.but when go to create content and click the "test" link my added field is not appearing.anyone knows.??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have appropriate permission. The appropriate url should be something like this `admin/content/node-type/CONTENT_TYPE_NAME/fields`

Comment: I go to the link as you mention above (change the content type name,in my case i have a "test" content-type) i can add new fields , remove .But problem is that it is not appearing when i go to create a content.

Comment: in admin/content/node-type/CONTENT_TYPE_NAME/template, do <?php print_r($node->field_machine_readable_name) ?> to see what gets printed.